# Issue with overloading http verbs for route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

We are using the same action in a controller (called 'residential_springs') to process and render a form

```
def index
  //..code...
  if params[:authenticity_token]
    if process_post(params)
      redirect_to checkout_index_url 
    end
  end
end

def process_post(params)
  return true 
end
```

And then in the routes we have

```
get "residential_springs/index"
post "residential_springs/index"
```

The form actually points to this action

```
=form_for @order_garage_door, :url => {:action => 'index'} do |f|
//form stuff...
```

yet we keep getting the routing error

```
No route matches "/residential_springs/index"
```

The crazy thing is we've already set this up a ton in this project and it works fine for other controllers so we know we're missing something crazy small and dumb.  But I think everyone on the project has tunnel vision and fresh eyes would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you output any possible relevant portion of `rake routes`?

Comment: `residential_springs_index GET    /residential_springs/index(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"residential_springs", :action=>"index"}
                                                POST   /residential_springs/index(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"residential_springs", :action=>"index"}`

Comment: Welp, that's maddening. Any caching systems? Restart the dev server? Have you tried shaking your computer physically?

Comment: yes, yes and yes(well, strangling motions in the air)

Comment: Probably won't help, but if you haven't tried, maybe clone a new working directory on another machine.. *shrug* I'm sure there's better advice out there, though.

Comment: Does your code inherit from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: yes it does inherit ApplicationController, the route does work for the get verb just not for the post.